# Max and Where Clause

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to retrive maximum of one column in the table which meets some where criteria. I tried the following SQL

```
Select Name, Max(version) from table1 where name="Asdf";
```

I am getting resultset which has more names than I gave in the where clause. What do you think is wrong with the above query?

Thank you in advance

Note: its Sybase Database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mix aggregate functions and normal column selects. Try

```
select max(version) 
from table1 
where Name = 'Asdf'
```

or use a `group by` to get all names and their `max(version)`:

```
select Name, Max(version) 
from table1 
group by Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `group by` clause when dealing with aggregate functions:

```
Select Name, Max(version) from table1 where name="Asdf" Group by Name
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not including the name field in your select. if you want to get that then try...

```
Select top 1 name, version 
from table1
where name = 'Asdf'
order by version desc
```

Answer (score 0):

this should give you back the data set that you are looking for. 
It should only give you the max version for the name "Asdf". 
If this is not the data set that you wanted please give an example data set.

SQL Query:

```
Select Name, version 
from table1 
where name="Asdf"
having max(version) = version
```

if there are more than one row in the data base with the same name and the max version and you only want one row returned in the data set. Make these changes to the

SQL Query:

```
Select top 1 Name, version 
from table1 
where name="Asdf"
having max(version) = version
```

or if you want to do a set of names:

```
Select distinct Name, version 
from table1 
where name in ("Asdf", "ghjk")
having max(version) = version
```